# I'm searching for the title of an old series about a random girl living in a creepy mansion with the weirdest family

Tags: story-identification, anime

I can't remember it quite clearly, but the girl kinda got lost in the forest, or something like that. Somehow she ended in a rather creepy mansion with a very strange fantasy-like family. One of the members of said family was a very disturbing woman inside a tree, and you could only see her face from a hole in the tree.

Comment: How old is the series?  When did you read it?  Was this a comic book? Novel?

Comment: Probably an anime, not book